# OpenCL SDK for intel core 2 due

Tags: sdk, opencl, intel

Where could I find OpenCL SDK for intel core 2 due?
Graphic card: mobile intel (r) series express chipset family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current intel OpenCL SDK does not support Core 2 Duo Series CPUs. ([See release notes](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdk-for-opencl-applications-2013-release-notes))

If, however, you want to use that kind of CPU for OpenCL (development), you can use the AMD APP SDK. It supports all CPUs with at least SSE 2.x, as can be seen [here](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/system-requirements-driver-compatibility/)

Works for me (Core2Duo 6750, Ubuntu)

Comment: I already tried to use AMD but I can't find my "Mobile Intel (R) series express chipset" CPU in the [drivers list](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx)..

Comment: Your Graphics Chip does not support OpenCL. The only way to use it is by using the CPU, which supports SSE 2.x and thus can be used with the AMD APP SDK.